# trying to convert time into EST time zone

Tags: javascript

Trying to convert local date time into EST time with following code and getting EST time but it is one hour less,for example if it is 6.00 EST the it is showing me 5.00 EST.
Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong ?

```
var offset = -5.0;
var fromDate = new Date(selectedDate); // selected date is String of date which is set currently
var utcFromTime = fromDate.getTime() + (fromDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var effFromDate = new Date(utcFromTime + (3600000 * offset));
alert("final EST :" + effFromDate);
```

Comment: Daylight savings? is the offset always -5 i know here in Switzerland we swing from +1 to +2 depending on time of the year when compared to UTC

Comment: i dont know, cant we have dynamic offset which can work in day light savings and normal time as well ?

Comment: Working with time is always such a headache when it comes to things like that i just stand on the shoulders of giants and use moment.js

Comment: yes agreed, do you have any link through which i can download and understand the use of moment.js ?

Comment: their documentation is excellent, http://momentjs.com/, they have moment and moment timezone which sounds like just the thing you want

Comment: +1 on momentjs.com - It's a great library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So using [moment](http://momentjs.com/) and [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) you can do this

```
//create new moment with local time then update the timezone
var localTimeInMurica = moment().tz("EST");


//display EST time of the local time orgionally passed

//see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ for options on displaying the date
console.log(localTimeInMurica.format());
```

here is a fiddle (i included moment timezone in the manually rather than through a cdn as i wanted to get the latest with all the years) http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/61j008n0/

for EDT

```
//create new moment with local time then update the timezone
var localTimeInMurica = moment().tz("America/New_York");


//display EST time of the local time orgionally passed

//see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ for options on displaying the date
console.log(localTimeInMurica.format());
```

Comment: we should declare it and defined somewhere !

Comment: oh, must be running timezone before loading moment, update fiddle so that moment timezone zone is part of the domready bit, normally this would be it's own resource but i couldn;t find a cnd hosted version with all the timezones

Comment: Hang on were you on about the fiddle or when you tried it yourself? As the fiddle was working for me even before I updated it.

Comment: actually i tried by adding two js file 1)moment-timezone-with-data.js 2)moment.js, now after changing order error gone. Thanks again

Comment: but still it is showing time 1 hour behind, did you try to convert any time.For me it is lagging by one hour.

Comment: yeah mine shows correctly 9:15 am. If you try the fiddle what time do you get? mine is always -5 of UTC

Comment: you fiddle is not giving any output, how to run it. i tried to convert 20:00 IST to EST and it showed 9:35 instead 10:35.

Comment: just read that there are two forms of eastern time EST and EDT which is the one with the daylight savings and some places use. So EST never changes but regions within EST may currently be on EDT so only -4

Comment: yeah that is right you are 5.5 hrs + UTC EST is -5 hrs. however EDT which some parts of EST are currently using are -4 which would be 10:35. so if you want EDT use EDT as the timezone

Comment: i tried putting America/NewYork instead of EST and now its working fine for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ah yeah that's what i was just about to suggest then you don;t have to worry about EST or EDT just a location and moment will do the rest.

Comment: any idea why it is giving output like this "2014-09-08T11:33:00-04:00"

Comment: yeah that is the default format, have a look at the display section in moment docs http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ on different formats

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I think that you can't do this using JavaScript because it doesn't handle time zones.
You should use a language such as PHP and get the result back to JavaScript using Ajax.

Answer (score -1):

using this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate)

```
var UTC = new Date();
var UTC = UTC.getTime() // Get UTC Timestamp
```

By setting hours and minutes of timezone

```
var IST = new Date(date); // Clone UTC Timestamp
IST.setHours(IST.getHours() + 5); // set Hours to 5 hours later
IST.setMinutes(IST.getMinutes() + 30); // set Minutes to be 30 minutes later
```

or using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
var dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");
dec = dec.tz('America/New_York');
```

Comment: but doesn't the offset change depending on the time of year? also this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) let soemone else handle timezones

Comment: Generally, there's this genius library called moment.js that can help dealing with dates. because the Date object is a pain to deal with.